# Managing Model Changes in ASP.NET MVC Razor Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, razor

I am working on a business application which is being developed from scratch. We have opted to design our business logic using Entity Framework, and since the application has to be delivered on the Web we have selected MVC 3 (Razor) for presentation.

Things are pretty fine yet, but I am afraid how will I manage if anytime in the future we need to change our Entity Classes (like adding/removing fields in the business entities or adding more relational entities etc.). I know I can update my model by selecting "Update Model from Database" in Visual Studio (we are using Database first approach). In this case will I have to scrap my old views and generate new ones or is there any way I can update my exiting views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That questions a little ambigous, so I'll talk about MVC concepts

The whole approach of MVC is "serperation of concerns" so you should be able to lititimatly change your Model (database, entity Framework, etc.) without updating your controllers or views.

That said your model's responsibillity is to return the data required by the controller/view. So it needs to be consistant. So if you model is bound to a view that return data x, if this view is updated, moved to a new platform, etc, etc then the model should still return the same basic information (for it to continue to work with your existing views/controllers).

If your using code first then you should be able to generate any required db views, etc. on a new db, providing this db supports code first generation (so basically MS-SQL I believe)

Comment: Yes I just realized that views do not have to be regenerated unless we make change in the model in such a way that view no longer completely represents the model. e.g adding a NOT NULL field in an entity and not adding a field in the view.

Answer (score 0):

When using Editor- or DisplayFor you can pass in the entire model and it will show all the properties on the model.